# Show that $R \cap R^{−1}$ is an equivalence relation on $X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, relations

> Let $R$ be a reflexive and transitive relation on $X$. Show that $R \cap R^{−1}$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

I am stuck and feel like I am doing something wrong, any help would be much appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

$R = \{1,2,3\}$

$X = \{2,3,4,5,6\}$

$R$ on $X = \{(1,2), (1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,6),(3,6)\}$

$R^{-1} = \{1,1/2,1/3\}$

$R \cap R^{-1} = \{1\}$

$R^{-1}$ on $X = \{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)(1,6)\}$

TRUE

Am I completely off-base or am I close?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define $R^{-1}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question? Do you mean the inverse of R?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation (or even the idea!), but I strongly suspect $R^{-1}$ is the relation you get by just reversing the order of the ordered pairs. That is, if $(x,y) \in R$, then $(y,x) \in R^{-1}$. So I'm not sure what you've got here, your $R$ doesn't really look like a relation, just a set.

Comment: Like I said, I might be completely off base :( this one really confused me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a relation $R$ on a set $X$ (that is, a subset of the Cartesian product $X \times X$ of orders pairs of things in $X$), the relation $R^{-1}$ is the [inverse relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_relation) formed by taking the ordered pairs in $R$ and reversing them; that is,

$$R^{-1} = \{(y, x): (x, y) \in R\}.$$

This should remind you of inverse functions, where 'input' and 'output' are reversed.

---

OK, so to prove that $R \cap R^{-1}$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, you need to show that it's

- reflexive by showing that $(x, x) \in R \cap R^{-1}$ for all $x \in X$,
- symmetric by showing that **if** $(x, y)$ is in $R \cap R^{-1}$ **then** $(y, x)$ is too, and
- transitive by showing that **if** $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$ are in $R \cap R^{-1}$, **then** $(x, z)$ is as well.

To do that, I would show that $R^{-1}$ is both reflexive and transitive, given that $R$ is. That $R^{-1}$ is reflexive should be immediate, realizing it's transitive requires a *little* something more; namely working backwards (literally; everything is just flipped around in $R^{-1}$).

Then you'll have to convince yourself that the intersection of two reflexive and transitive relations on $X$ is reflexive and transitive as well. At which point, you just need to show that $R \cap R^{-1}$ is symmetric.

In fact, regardless of any properties $R$ has, $R \cap R^{-1}$ is *always* symmetric; here's a picture of a relation on $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ for your intuition (points in $R \cap R^{-1}$ are outlined in orange in the last picture):

[image]

To actually show $R \cap R^{-1}$ is symmetric, assume $(x, y) \in R \cap R^{-1}$, so that $(x, y) \in R$ and $(x, y) \in R^{-1}$. What do each of those statements tell us about $(y, x)$?

Comment: I really appreciate the help, this made it so much clearer for me!

Answer (score 0):

A binary relation on $X$ is any subset of $R \times R$.And $R^{-1}=\{(x,y) : (y,x)\in R\}$.Now  $(x,y) \in  (R \cap R^{-1}$ iff $((x,y) \in R$  and $(y,x)\in R)$. From this it should be obvious that if $R$ is transitive then  $R\cap R^{-1}$ is also transitive.